# quicksort program provides partially sorted output

Tags: c, debugging

Below simple quick sort code with last element as pivot,almost works but except the last element fails to get sorted. Any thoughts where this program went wrong?

Here's the output:

```
$a.out
 4 3 5 2 1 3 2 3 //input
 1 2 2 3 3 3 5 4 //output
```

Simple swap looks fine

```
void swap ( int* a, int* b )
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

Hmm..fine too ..may issue with `end`?

```
int partition(int a[],int start,int end){
int pivot = a[end];
int pindex=start;int i;

    for ( i=start; i <= end-1; i++){
       if (a[i] <= pivot){
           swap(&a[i],&a[pindex]);pindex++;
       }
    }
    swap(&a[pindex],&a[pivot]);
    return (pindex + 1);
}
```

Surely looks good.

```
void quicksort(int a[],int start,int end){
int pindex;

    if (start < end){
        pindex = partition(a,start,end-1);
        quicksort(a,start,pindex-1);
        quicksort(a,pindex+1,end);
    }
}
```

Simple main call

```
int main(){
    int a[8] = {4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3};
    int i=0;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
    quicksort(a,0,8);
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf(" %d", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your code through an autoindenter? One thing is that it sometimes reveals unwanted flow control statements, the other thing is that it makes your question here readable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will  run it through autoindenter, here after :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review `partition` function.

It should return

```
 return pindex;
```

instead of `pindex+1`.

Because, just take the following case:

`1 2 3 4 5`

As `5` is chosen as pivot, it should return `4`, not `5` as pivot index.

Check for the invariant that `pindex` must lie between start and end (both inclusive). If pivot is to be lie at end, it must not pass the end.

Generally, partition starts from both end. You are starting it from the one end. Try to do it both the end for efficiency. Otherwise, in the `1 2 3 4 5`, you will keep swapping with the same element (1 with 1, 2 with 2 and so on).

And in the partition:

```
swap(&a[pindex],&a[pivot]);
```

should be

```
 swap(&a[pindex],&a[end]);
```

`pivot` was a value, not an index.

Another change, you required `quicksort`,

```
  if (start < end){
  pindex = partition(a,start,end-1);
  //As here index is one past last, so make it start..pindex
  quicksort(a,start,pindex);
  quicksort(a,pindex+1,end);
  }
```

Your partition function should be

```
int partition(int a[],int start,int end){

int pivot = a[end];
int pindex=start;int i;

for ( i=start; i <= end-1; i++){
    if (a[i] <= pivot){
        swap(&a[i],&a[pindex]);pindex++;
        }
    }

    swap(&a[pindex],&a[end]);
    return (pindex);
}
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme. This partition scheme is used here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made those two changes. sadly, still the output is not in sorted order.

Comment: @ameyCU are you sure ? I get **12233453**

Comment: @Michi Hmm ideone gave wrong answer with it . My system gave correct answer . o.0

Comment: @ameyCU I use Ubuntu 64BIT + GCC

Comment: Yes, I can see it now, final swap statement messed it up. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay couple of changes

As doptimusprime pointed return pindex

```
int partition(int a[],int start,int end){
    int pivot = a[end];
    int pindex=start;int i;
    for ( i=start; i <= end-1; i++){
        if (a[i] <= pivot){
            swap(&a[i],&a[pindex]);pindex++;
        }
    }
    swap(&a[pindex],&a[end]);
    return (pindex);
}
```

Adjust your quicksort function accordingly

```
void quicksort(int a[],int start,int end){
    int pindex;

    if (start < end){
        pindex = partition(a,start,end-1);
        quicksort(a,start,pindex); // no pindex-1
        quicksort(a,pindex+1,end);
    }
}
```

Comment: works properly. thumbs up. note the final swap in partition - swapping between current pIndex value and partition end value, instead of the pivot value.

Answer (score 0):

Your program fails if someone type negative numbers.
Why are you complicating things like that ?

Here is a simple sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubble_sort(int *array, int length){
  int i,j, k, temp;

  for (i = 0 ; i < length-1; i++){
    for (k = 0 ; k < length-i-1; k++){
      if (array[k] > array[k+1]){
        temp = array[k];
        array[k]   = array[k+1];
        array[k+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

    printf("The sorted Array List:\n\n");

  for ( j = 0 ; j < length ; j++ ){
    printf("%d  ", array[j]);
  }
}

int main(void){
    int array[8] = {4, 3, 5, 2, 1, -1, 2, 3};
    int length = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];

    bubble_sort(array, length);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> -1  1  2  2  3  3  4  5

Comment: That's a bubble sort . Question asked about quick sort . I think it is irrrelevent .

Comment: Thanks for the bubble sort. I just wanted to learn/understand quicksort better  - which is much efficient for larger data sets.

Comment: So this is not what you need ?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to fix quicksort. (not looking for sorting method in general)

Comment: @wewmi What is your intention here  (**8**)  inside **quicksort(a,0,8);** is length of the array or **a[8]** which is wrong ?

Comment: @Michi  Yes that's correct but while passing to `partition` it is passed as `end-1` so it doesn't make any problem .Also `a[8]` wont occur in any part of code. So it is fine .

Comment: @ameyCU Anyway the program will fail when negative numbers are present

Comment: @Michi  Why do you think that ?

Comment: @ameyCU change the OPs code **int a[8] = {4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3};** with **int a[8] = {4, 3, 5, 2, -1, 3, 2, 3};**

Comment: @ameyCU well i get seg fault and ideone gave me this  **-1219162989 -1 2 3 3 3 5 4**  http://ideone.com/rHbwJo

Comment: @Michi Yeah on my system I get correct output . On ideone it gives me rubbsh answer .  Maybe your are right .

Comment: @ameyCU He should check it with a debugger :)).

Comment: @Michi Yeah that surely be helpful

Comment: **Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==4523==    at 0x2004005BB: ???
==4523==    by 0xF053D9797595E9FF: ???
==4523==    by 0xFFEFFFE2F: ???
==4523==  Address 0x2004005bb is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd**